# How do I dynamically render an InnerBlock inside a dynamic block?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I am building a custom website with custom blocks and have recently decided to translate all my blocks into dynamic blocks. The blocks that do not use `InnerBlocks` are fine, but I cannot figure out how to render a dynamic `InnerBlock` inside another dynamic block.

I used the advice from another post to mix the `save()` method and return `InnerBlocks.Content`, after which you render the `InnerBlocks` content with `$content` inside the `render_callback` function. This is what it looks like:

```
// counter/save.js
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { InnerBlocks } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

const Save = (props) => {
  return <><InnerBlocks.Content /></>;
};
export default Save;
```

```
// counter.php
function counter_render_callback($attr, $content)
{
  ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering

?>

  <?php if (!empty($content)) : ?>
  <section class="bg-blue-900 thin text-white">
    <div class="container flex flex-wrap justify-evenly md:justify-around text-center -mb-10 md:mb-0">
      <?php echo do_blocks($content); ?>
    </div>
  </section>
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php
  /* END HTML OUTPUT */

  $output = ob_get_contents(); // collect output
  ob_end_clean(); // Turn off ouput buffer

  return $output; // Print output
};
```

Now I set up my `InnerBlock` to also act as a dynamic block, but it only renders that which I set up in it's `save.js` file. This is what the `InnerBlock` looks like:

```
// counter-list/save.js
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";

const Save = (props) => {
  const { attributes } = props;

  const mandatoryFields = () => {
    return attributes.amount && attributes.label;
  };

  const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
  return (
    <div {...blockProps}>
      {mandatoryFields() && (
        <div class="w-1/2 sm:w-1/3 md:w-auto mb-10 md:mb-0">
          <div class="font-display text-h1 font-medium leading-none">
            {attributes.amount}
          </div>
          <div class="w-10 h-px bg-white my-4 inline-block opacity-60"></div>
          <div>{attributes.label}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Save;
```

```
// counter-list.php
function counter_list_render_callback($attr, $content)
{
  // Easier access to all attributes
  $amount = !empty($attr['amount']) ? $attr['amount'] : "";
  $label = !empty($attr['label']) ? $attr['label'] : "";

  // Do not output anything if any of the mandatory fields are empty
  if (empty($amount) || empty($label)) {
    return;
  }

  ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering

?>

<div class="w-1/2 sm:w-1/3 md:w-auto mb-10 md:mb-0">
  <div class="font-display text-h1 font-medium leading-none"><?php echo $amount; ?></div>
  <div class="w-10 h-px bg-white my-4 inline-block opacity-60"><?php echo $label; ?></div>
</div>

<?php
  /* END HTML OUTPUT */

  $output = ob_get_contents(); // collect output
  ob_end_clean(); // Turn off ouput buffer

  return $output; // Print output
};
```

How do I make my `counter.php` file use the `render_callback` function from `counter-list.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the question, I'll answer the question myself for those that seek to find the same answer. My `InnerBlock` was called `counter-list.php`, which causes a problem as I have a `counter_list_render_callback` function. When looping through all my blocks, it tries to find `counter-list_render_callback` which is an invalid function name and therefore fails to render.

Make sure to name your files so that you can reuse their names for the `render_callback` functions.